# boost asio::async_write() takes too long

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [boost::async_write takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395569/boostasync-write-takes-too-long)

In my server application, I run asio service in one theread to deal about 100 connections. I found the async_write() takes too long sometimes, about 15ms.(The packet is very small)

My question is why async_write() takes so long time? I think the async_write() should return immediately. So slowly is difficult to send many data.
I means that,the function not return immediately. I'm not said that the send not complete immediately. 15ms is too long for a synchronous function. And the application is really blocked. (dont care GetTickCount )

Testing code like this:

```
uint64_t TStart = 0, TEnd = 0;
TStart = GetTickCount();

async_write(*this->m_Socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(pSendData->m_buf.GetBuffer(), pSendData->m_buf.GetSize()),
    boost::bind(&SttSocketConnection::OnSended, this,
    pSendData, placeholders::error, placeholders::bytes_transferred));

TEnd = GetTickCount();
if (TEnd - TStart > 1) {
    __asm int 3;
    TStart = TEnd;
}
```

Comment: You want an asynchronous function to complete immediately? I guess you don't understand what asynchronous means.

Comment: I haven't used the boost functionality in question, but in general the synchronous part of an asynchronous write should complete very quickly UNLESS there's a buffer size limit and it reverts to synchronous operation.  Perhaps if you do some tests on number of outstanding writes when one blocks, affects of changing buffer sizes (if you can) etc. you'll find a correlation.

Comment: Don't keep posting the same question.  If you want to understand why `async_write()` takes the time it does, just ask that.

Comment: Also, a quick google suggests `GetTickCount()` isn't reliable when your samples are taken on different cores, which could easily happen if the scheduler moves the thread between your `TStart =` and `TEnd =` lines.  No millisecond-or-better Windows OS timing routines are reliable across cores, as they rely on the CPU clock tick registers which are core specific and HALs often don't sync them.  So, your timings may have an effectively random delta, swamping the actual time taken.

Comment: Sorry,I means that,the function not return immediately. I'm not said that the send not complete immediately. 15ms is too long for a synchronous function.

Comment: And the application is really blocked very long time. (dont care GetTickCount in Win OS )

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate, but the question that it duplicates "has been removed for reasons of moderation". Moderation in all things, except moderation?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're incurring a context switch somewhere. 15ms is the scheduling quantum on a multiprocessor Windows machine.

If it doesn't always happen very often, don't worry about it, you just got hit by a context switch when you made a system call.

If you have the problem on every call, you should follow the system calls through, and find out which one causes the context switch. I have seen similar problems when using IO completion ports, serial ports and small timeouts, where some system calls always end up with a 15ms latency. To fix it I had to restructure the code so that the completion of async operations did not involve a timer.

I do not know exactly what is causing this problem with asio. You should follow the system calls down and find out which one incurs the latency.

Comment: Thanks! I found the reaseion. I only used single thread to run asio and message loop. like this: while(!stoping){ io.reset(); io.poll();  taskqueue.excute();}  I removed io.reset(), everything is ok.

Comment: Cozyboy, what is your " io " variable, please ?